# How to set a value of one hidden field to another hidden field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, hidden-field

I'm using PHP, Smarty, jQuery(jquery-1.7.1.min.js), AJAX, etc. 
Following is my HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="que_id" name="que_id" value=76539 />
```

I'm having another input of type hidden as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="question_id" id="question_id" value=""/>
```

Now what I want to achieve is when the page loads completely, set the value of first input hidden field to the second hidden input field. How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#question_id").val($("#que_id").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#question_id').val($('#que_id').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: @Echo I just added that for a safety, but that's not necessary really, we dont need to wait until the page's resource loads.. :)

Comment: I didn't think there is some safety needed :P.  So follow "KISS"

Answer (score 1):

```
var first_hidden_Value = $('#que_id').val();

$('#question_id').val(first_hidden_Value);
```

You have to do this in `document.ready()`;

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. try this code:

```
$(function(){//ensure document is ready 
  $('#question_id').val($('#que_id').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your document ready, you can just grab the element using the ID selector and just use the `.val()` method, which can both return and set the value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#question_id').val( $('#que_id').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put this code in header tag

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var a = $('#que_id').val();
 $('#question_id').val(a);
});
```

Comment: it is not necessary to put in header tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    var hidden1 = $('#que_id').val();

    $('#question_id').val(hidden1);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

User this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var que_id = $('#que_id').val(); 
    $('#question_id').val(que_id);

});
```